# Reversing each individual action in an SKAction sequence without reversing the order of all actions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to create a `SKAction` sequence and then reverse each of the actions individually, without reversing the overall order.

I originally tried this via the `reverse()` method in the `SKAction` object, but this is not quite what I want. [From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417817-sequence):

> This action is reversible; it creates a new sequence action that reverses the order of the actions. Each action in the reversed sequence is itself reversed. For example, if an action sequence is {1,2,3}, the reversed sequence would be {3R,2R,1R}.

I require {1R,2R,3R} as the new action instead. For example, if I had:

```
let rotate = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, duration: 0.5)
let scale = SKAction.scale(by: 2, duration: 0.5)
let action = SKAction.sequence([rotate, scale])
```

I would want to apply some function to the `action` action to produce a new action, which is equivalent to:

```
let rotate = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, duration: 0.5)
let scale = SKAction.scale(by: 0.5, duration: 0.5)
let action = SKAction.sequence([rotate, scale])
```

Is there a way this could be achieved without programming this flipped action seperately? To do this, I thought a possibility could be to break the sequence back down into its individual actions, reverse them, and build a new action from these, but I can't seem to find a way to break `rotation` back down into the two individual rotations again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by creating another sequence but with the actions reversed, so:

```
let actionReversed = SKAction.sequence([rotate.reversed(), scale.reversed()])
```

If you wanted to run the actions "forward", on completion "reverse" them, you could use something like this:

```
  yourspritenode!.run(action) { [self] in
    yourspritenode!.run(actionReversed)
  }
```